# how to fix google search console with sitemaps org schemas sitemap 0.9 code

Tags: search, console

any one let me know the solution of this type error
also check screen shot below :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OSM7.png)
https://theodysseynews.com/sitemap_news.xml
**html, body, *, *::before, *::after, html body *, #allow-copy_script ~ body * { -webkit-user-select: initial !important; user-select: initial !important; }**